# How to summarize pytorch model

Tags: python, pytorch

Hello I am building a DQN model for reinforcement learning on cartpole and want to print my model summary like keras model.summary() function

Here is my model class.

```
class DQN():
    ''' Deep Q Neural Network class. '''
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim=64, lr=0.05):
            super(DQN, self).__init__()
            self.criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
            self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(
                            torch.nn.Linear(state_dim, hidden_dim),
                            torch.nn.ReLU(),
                            torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim*2),
                            torch.nn.ReLU(),
                            torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, action_dim)
                    )
            self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr)



    def update(self, state, y):
        """Update the weights of the network given a training sample. """
        y_pred = self.model(torch.Tensor(state))
        loss = self.criterion(y_pred, Variable(torch.Tensor(y)))
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()


    def predict(self, state):
        """ Compute Q values for all actions using the DQL. """
        with torch.no_grad():
            return self.model(torch.Tensor(state))
```

Here is the model instance with the parameters passed.

```
# Number of states = 4
n_state = env.observation_space.shape[0]
# Number of actions = 2
n_action = env.action_space.n
# Number of episodes
episodes = 150
# Number of hidden nodes in the DQN
n_hidden = 50
# Learning rate
lr = 0.001


simple_dqn = DQN(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)
```

I tried using torchinfo summary but I get an AttributeError:
'DQN' object has no attribute 'named_parameters'

```
from torchinfo import summary
simple_dqn = DQN(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)
summary(simple_dqn, input_size=(4, 2, 50))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DQN` should be a subclass of `nn.Module`

```py
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim=64, lr=0.05):
        ...
```